# Reading Keyboard Input using AdaGtk

Tags: gtk, ada

I am using Ada together with the Gtk library.
I would like to read the user's keyboard input and react individually on it, depending which keys he/she pressed. How can I access the keyboard input from the user?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're looking for: 1) keystrokes or 2) editable text.

1. The game [`LinXtris`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/linxtris/?source=directory) handles main window [`key_press_event`](http://linxtris.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/linxtris/linxtris/src/main_window_pkg.adb?revision=1.15&view=markup) signals in the procedure [`On_Main_Window_Key_Pressed`](http://linxtris.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/linxtris/linxtris/src/main_window_pkg-callbacks.adb?revision=1.5&view=markup), which passes each `Gdk.Event.Gdk_Event_Key` on to the `Game_Engine`.
2. The [`Interaction`](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/GUI_component_interaction#Ada) demo cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13514358/230513) has a `Gtk.Editable` that handles `Signal_Insert_Text` in the procedure `On_Insert_Text`. The advantage is that the handler is called for single keystrokes, as well as pasted text.