# what is the standard ada include path

Tags: database-connection, ada

Im using gnat4.6 on Ubuntu installed using apt-get. I need to know where to install downloaded libraries like [APQ](http://sourceforge.net/projects/apq/). What should I set my `ADA_INCLUDE_PATH` and `ADA_OBJECTS_PATH` to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The beauty of Ada support in Debian (on which Ubuntu is based) is that you don't need to mess with `ADA_INCLUDE_PATH` and friends; supported libraries are installed where the GNAT Project Manager expects to find them. Say `gnatls -v` to see the default values.

To use the system as intended, you will find it much simpler to use the GNAT Project Manager; you'd say, in your `my_project.gpr` file,

```
with "apq";
project My_Project is
   ...
```

and build with

```
$ gnatmake -P my_project
```

There's [online documentation for GPR](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn_unw/GNAT-Project-Manager.html), but I wouldn't call it particularly user-friendly. There's [a set of Youtube videos](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o1cLLhtBNpk) (I haven't looked at them in any detail; their stated interest is large systems, but hang in there).

Comment: +1 Leave the APQ libs where `apt-get` puts them and cite the libraries in your build script; see also these [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13479748/230513).

Comment: I use gnatmake to build how do I cite my build paths in a correct way?

Comment: If you say `gnatls -v` it shows at the end that the project search path includes `/usr/share/ada/adainclude`; when you install `libapq1-dev` it puts `apq.gpr` there for `gnatmake` to find when you say `with "apq";` in your `.gpr`. All the build paths needed to use APQ are then sorted out for you without you needing to do anything else; there is no need to mess around with `-aI` or `-aO`. To summarise, the "correct way" to build with libraries that have gone to the trouble of providing you with GPR files is **to use them**. I'm not saying they're always right, of course, but give it a try!

Answer (score 2):

> I use gnatmake to build; how do I cite my build paths in a correct way?

The relevant options are shown in [*6.2 Switches for gnatmake: Source and library search path switches*](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/gnat_ugn_unw/Switches-for-gnatmake.html#Switches-for-gnatmake).

Addendum: The development package is `libapq3.2.0-dev`.

- The manual is in `/usr/share/doc/libapq3.2.0-dev/manual.pdf.gz`
- An example and corresponding `.gpr` file are in `/usr/share/doc/libapq3.2.0-dev/examples`. As @Simon suggested, the `.gpr` file begins:

  ```
  with "apq.gpr";
  project APQ.Samples is
  ```
- The Ada include files are in `/usr/share/ada/adainclude/apq`.
- The libraries are in `/usr/lib`.

```
$ dpkg -L libapq3.2.0-dev
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/ada
/usr/share/ada/adainclude
/usr/share/ada/adainclude/apq
/usr/share/ada/adainclude/apq/apq_helper.ads
/usr/share/ada/adainclude/apq/apq_helper.adb
/usr/share/ada/adainclude/apq/apq.adb
/usr/share/ada/adainclude/apq/apq.ads
/usr/share/ada/adainclude/apq.gpr
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libapq3.2.0-dev
/usr/share/doc/libapq3.2.0-dev/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libapq3.2.0-dev/manual.pdf.gz
/usr/share/doc/libapq3.2.0-dev/examples
/usr/share/doc/libapq3.2.0-dev/examples/apq-samples.adb
/usr/share/doc/libapq3.2.0-dev/examples/apq-samples.ads
/usr/share/doc/libapq3.2.0-dev/examples/apq-samples.gpr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/libapq.a
/usr/lib/ada
/usr/lib/ada/adalib
/usr/lib/ada/adalib/apq
/usr/lib/ada/adalib/apq/apq_helper.ali
/usr/lib/ada/adalib/apq/apq.ali
/usr/share/doc/libapq3.2.0-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/lib/libapq.so
```

Comment: I don't think we should confuse the issue with GtkAda examples when we don't know whether `apq.gpr` will do the trick for APQ!

Comment: @SimonWright: I agree; I've updated the answer to complement yours.