# Requesting examples/tutorials for using ada APQ

Tags: ada

I have looked a great deal on google but can't seem to find any examples of how to use [APQ](http://sourceforge.net/projects/apq/) for ada95. If any one have experience of using this library I would be grateful for any small example.

Comment: A link to APQ might be helpful...

Comment: Thanks I decided to use gnatcoll instead. If any one needs an example of that feel free to comment below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [manual](http://apq.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/apq/apq/apq-manual.pdf?view=log) is fairly comprehensive, and the [source](http://apq.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/apq/apq/) includes several directories of examples: `eg*`.

Comment: I saw that. I seem to have trouble with installing the package though.

Comment: The [`apt-get`](http://askubuntu.com/q/20031) command should identify dependencies, but you might use the Ubuntu Software Center GUI verify what's installed.

Comment: See also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14655482/230513) to a related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14643609/230513).